# On Deriving Divergence in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm trying to derive divergence in cylindrical coordinates.

Suppose we have a vector function expressed in cylindrical coordinates: $$\textbf{F}=F_R\textbf{e}_R+F_\theta\textbf{e}_\theta+F_z\textbf{k}$$

I know that grad in cylindrical coordinates is:

$$\nabla=\textbf{e}_R\frac{\partial}{\partial 
 R}+\textbf{e}_\theta\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial}{\partial 
 \theta}+\textbf{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial 
 z}$$

So:

$$\nabla \cdot \textbf{F} = (\textbf{e}_R\frac{\partial}{\partial 
 R}+\textbf{e}_\theta\frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial}{\partial 
 \theta}+\textbf{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial 
 z}) \cdot \textbf{F} $$

My question is, when you expand this dot product, why do you get:

$$\nabla \cdot \textbf{F} = (\textbf{e}_R\cdot\frac{\partial \textbf{F}}{\partial 
 R}+\frac{1}{R}\textbf{e}_\theta \cdot \frac{\partial \textbf{F}}{\partial 
 \theta}+\textbf{k} \cdot \frac{\partial \textbf{F}}{\partial 
 z})$$

and not:

$$\nabla \cdot \textbf{F} = (\textbf{e}_R \cdot \textbf{F} \frac{\partial}{\partial 
 R}+\textbf{e}_\theta \cdot \textbf{F} \frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial}{\partial 
 \theta}+\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{F} \frac{\partial}{\partial 
 z})$$

Which mathematical laws prescribe the former instead of the latter?

Thanks for any help,

Jack

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates. I hate the Del "operations", since they are not what they seem to be: it's an abuse of notation, which only works in cartesian coordinates. You have to view $\partial/\partial x$ as a "placeholder", and for the expression to have even a meaning, you can't leave them alone, they must read $\partial f/\partial x$.

Comment: If you have $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ but $x$ is parameterized as $x=x(t)$ then $$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = \frac{\tfrac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial t}}{\tfrac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}}$$ all this is the chain rule.